# With numpy, How can I insert a 2 dimentional array into a 3 dimentional array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'm new to python. When I trying to insert a 2-dimensional array into a 3d array, I got an error like this:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (9,9) into shape (9)
```

here is my code:

```
        tables = np.zeros((10, 9, 9))
        currentRoundTable = np.zeros((9, 9))
        np.insert(tables, 0, currentRoundTable)
        tables.pop()
```

the purpose is to create a queue, which tables[0] always the newest element (a 2d array), and the oldest will be poped up.

Anyone knows how can I solve this? Many thanks!

Comment: Just add `axis=0` to the insert call. Btw you cannot pop from an array like that.

Comment: @FelipeLanza Hi thank you! it works, and now my question becomes: how can I pop from an array like this. Haha!

Comment: `numpy` arrays are not optimal for queue like actions.  Both the action of inserting elements and removing them requires making a whole new array, a relatively expensive operation.

Comment: If you need a queue of arrays, you'll probably be better served with a `collections.deque`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.insert` returns a new array, so you always have to reassign it. Anyhow, you might consider handling both the insert- and pop-equivalent at once:

```
new_table = np.vstack([currentRoundTable[None, :, :], tables[:-1]])
# or to keep your own logic
new_table = np.insert(tables, 0, currentRoundTable, axis=0)[:-1]
```

That said, as suggested by @hpaulj, an array is really not optimal for handling a queue. Here is a more desirable alternative:

```
from collections import deque

queue = deque(tables, maxlen=10)
queue.pop()  # Drop the last item
queue.insert(0, currentRoundTable)  # Add the new table on top
```

Comment: Good learned a lot about python indexing from post +1